# Fortify Reports Buffer Overflow and Integer Overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, integer-overflow, fortify

Fortify reports a "Buffer Overflow" on line 20 (the `read` call of `readFully`) claiming the buffer size is 5, and the write length is 9. Fortify also reports an "Integer Overflow" on line 36 (the `g_malloc` call) in the following code:

```
 1  #include <glib.h>
 2  #include <stdio.h>
 3  #include <stdlib.h>
 4  #include <string.h>
 5  #include <unistd.h>
 6
 7  struct __attribute__((__packed__)) tlv
 8  {
 9    guint8 type;
10    guint32 length;
11    guint8 value[];
12  } tlv;
13
14  static gint32
15  readFully(int fd, void *target, guint32 size)
16  {
17    guint32 count = 0;
18    int bytes = 0;
19    while(count < size) {
20      bytes = read(fd, (guint8*)target + count, size - count);
21      if(-1 == bytes || 0 == bytes) {
22        return -1;
23      }
24      count += bytes;
25    }
26    return 0;
27  }
28
29  struct tlv *
30  get_tlv(int fd)
31  {
32    struct tlv pkt;
33    if(-1 == readFully(fd, &pkt, sizeof(pkt))) {
34      return NULL;
35    }
36    struct tlv* ret = g_malloc(pkt.length + sizeof(pkt));
37    memcpy(ret, &pkt, sizeof(pkt));
38    if(-1 == readFully(fd, ret->value, pkt.length)) {
39      g_free(ret);
40      return NULL;
41    }
42    return ret;
43  }
44
45  int
46  main(void)
47  {
48    printf("struct tlv:\t%lu\n", sizeof(struct tlv));
49    printf("guint32:\t%lu\n", sizeof(guint32));
50    printf("gsize:\t\t%lu\n", sizeof(gsize));
51    printf("size_t:\t\t%lu\n", sizeof(size_t));
52    return 0;
53  }
```

Output is as follows:

> ```
> struct tlv:     5
> guint32:        4
> gsize:          8
> size_t:         8
> ```

Buffer Overflow Analysis Evidence from Fortify:

[image: Fortify Analysis Evidence]

The Taints listed are as follows:

1. COMPARISON
2. NOT_NULL_TERMINATED
3. NUMBER
4. STREAM

This code is a smaller sample of code used to read a Type Length Value (TLV) field off of a network socket into a `struct tlv *`.

I don't see how it could either of these could be true, nor do I understand why it would trigger either of these. The Integer Overflow doesn't make any sense to me. [g_malloc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.48/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-malloc) takes a [gsize](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.48/glib-Basic-Types.html#gsize). Adding 5 to `guint32` couldn't possibly overflow.

Here's the way I'm running Fortify. I'm operating in a 64 bit environment on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.6.

```
$ sourceanalyzer -b sample gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-qual -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -g3 -Werror -c -o sample.o sample.c
$ sourceanalyzer -b sample -scan -f sample.fpr
$ auditworkbench sample.fpr
```

Comment: Further, *"Adding 5 to guint32 couldn't possibly overflow."* - yes it can, and legally. Pretty sure Fortify is telling you  if that `guint32` value is inside (max - 5) for that type it will *definitely* overflow, leaving you with a severely undersized allocation, which will appear to have "worked". Unrelated, are your TLV's, specifically the multi-byte scalars, already in host-order? I'm genuinely curious (never used glib before, so I honestly don't know).

Comment: @WhozCraig I cannot come up with any 32 bit value that adding 5 to could overflow 64 bits. I've removed the host-to-network and network-to-host code for brevity.

Comment: I must have missed where, in your post, there was any mention of a x64 build? The result of the expression `pkt.length + sizeof(pkt)` will be `guint32` unless `size_t` is a wider type (which is easy enough to check). Thereafter, regardless it will then become `gsize` (which defaults to `unsigned long`, not `size_t`) when fed to `g_malloc`. Therefore if `size_t` is 64bit, but `unsigned long` is 32bit, that's a problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was used to assuming 64 bits. I've updated the question to state it explicitly along with adding printfs for sizes of various things of interest.

Comment: That looks good. Thanks for the update. I'm interested in seeing what comes from this.

Comment: Could you post the output of Fortify with all the relevant context? There are two calls to `readFully`, and it would be useful to know which of the calls it thinks has buffer overflow. As for integer overflow, does Fortify still  report it if you explicitly cast `pkt.length` to `size_t`?

Comment: @Ruslan, I've added the Buffer Overflow Analysis Evidence diagram to the post. It still reports the integer overflow after explicitly casting `pkt.length` to `size_t`

Comment: Looks like Fortify knows that due to packing and flexible array `value` local structure `pkt` has size 5, but for some strange reason it evaluates `sizeof(pkt)` as if `value` had size 1, also forgetting about packing. And for integer overflow: what if you make separate `size_t` variables for the operands of the sum and another variable for the sum, and then pass the latter variable to `g_malloc`, does Fortify still report the overflow? Does the report point exactly to the line with the sum and nothing else? Does it report any particular numerical values leading to the overflow?

Comment: @Ruslan It doesn't give values for the overflow. Separating the values didn't change anything. It reports the g_malloc call as the integer overflow.

Comment: Oh, so it's not the sum which overflows, but the conversion of the argument? That's weird, given the sizes you've printed. And what if you use `gsize` instead of `size_t` for the separated values? Is the overflow still reported at the call site?

Comment: @Ruslan I just confirmed, all `size_t`, or `gsize`, or `guint64` all flag the `g_malloc` call as the integer overflow.

Comment: I'd report this strangeness to the developers. If it's not a bug (which I suspect it is), then at least a usability problem — that it doesn't provide better clues to understand what's going on.